# How do I delete a ci active record from db that is isolated in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter, active-record-query

This is the function in the CI model:

```
public function libraryClean() {
    $killCount=0;
    $rows=$this->db->get('mz')->result();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $rID=$row->rID;
        $title=$row->title;
        $char=$title[0];
        if (ctype_lower($char)) {
            $killCount++;
            // delete $row code goes here
        } 
    }
    return $killCount;
}
```

I've unsuccessfully tried various approaches. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just use an active record delete query.

```
$this->db->delete('mz', array('id' => $rID));
```

Being inside the foreach loop doesn't make the delete any more or less special.

Comment: Thanks.Works great. I don't quite understand though, when does '$this->db' forget about previously assigned select(), where(), etc. statements? Was it when I issued the $this->db->get('mz' )->result statement?

Comment: In this cae, it will "forget" when the function ends.  If you do a print_r on $rows, you will see that it is a list of all the rows in the table, while $row is one row in the table,  The code works because each row in the table should have a unique row id.  The cursor object will be "forgotten" when you instantiate a new cursor object, or when the function ends.

Comment: I'm not sure how to ask this but what if I did a select query using a 'where' qualifier to find if there were more than 20 rows with a certain value in a 'val' column before running the delete query above? Would it only delete the element with the id if it were in one of the rows that I had isolated that way? Or would I then need to write a separate function for the delete? I could find no info on what happens when there's more than one query in a model function. From what you said I'm feeling that the new function/query would be needed. Is that right?

Comment: I think it will only delete the id's from the select with the where clause?